# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory when using interval data type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am adding the below column in my entity class

```
@NonNull
@Column(name = "interval_value", nullable = false)
@Type(PostgreSQLIntervalType.class)
private Duration intervalValue;
```

When I use the

```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

I am getting error in the sql

Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL create commands for table :

module pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Root pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <relativePath /> 
 </parent>
```

How to add interval column using spring jpa entity ?

Comment: Do you mean Spring *Boot* version 3.1.0?

Comment: yes spring boot version

Comment: So fix your Question with that important detail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use the Duration type. The problem is that the Duration type isn't natively supported by PostgreSQL. While you're using the @Type(PostgreSQLIntervalType.class) annotation, it appears that Hibernate might not be able to properly map the Duration type to a PostgreSQL interval type.

To work around this issue, you might need to handle the mapping of the Duration type yourself, potentially by converting it to an appropriate format that PostgreSQL can understand.

Here's a general approach you can consider:

1- Create a custom attribute converter to convert between Duration and String representations that PostgreSQL can handle.

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.time.Duration;

@Converter
public class DurationToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Duration, String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Duration attribute) {
    return attribute.toString(); // Convert Duration to a format PostgreSQL understands
}

@Override
public Duration convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    return Duration.parse(dbData); // Convert back from the PostgreSQL format to Duration
 }
}
```

2 - Apply the custom attribute converter to your intervalValue field in your entity class.

```
@Entity
public class YourEntity {
// ...

@NonNull
@Column(name = "interval_value", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = DurationToStringConverter.class)
private Duration intervalValue;

// ... 
}
```

By using this custom attribute converter, you're effectively converting the Duration type to a String representation that PostgreSQL can handle, and then converting it back to a Duration when retrieving from the database.

Comment: Was this written by ChatGPT, or am I just high?

Comment: spring 3.x uses jakarta

Comment: Yes, you are right. So just change the package namespace from javax.* to jakarta.*.

Comment: did you use chatgpt or any similar AI at all to write any part of this answer?